# Where can I find the log of all mounted volumes?

Tags: mount, logs, disk-volume

To be more specific, I mean the file that keeps a history of every disk image/volume ever mounted. I know it exists because I found it once, but it was a long time ago and I have no idea how to find it again. It is similar to the InstallHistory.plist file, which logs every program ever installed.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the information in `/var/log/system.log` (or using the Console application). But the information is not kept forever.

For example:

```
Aug  4 07:34:34 ******** kernel[0]: hfs: mounted External on device disk3
Aug  4 07:34:44 ******** kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Time Machine on device disk5
```

and and a DMG

```
Aug  5 07:53:25 ******** kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Xcode on device disk6s2
```

After a while `system.log` is compressed and archived. To search in all the stored logs

```
cd /var/log/
(sudo cat system.log; sudo gzcat system.log.*) | grep mounted
```

Comment: I feel like it was specifically a list of DMGs that had been mounted, not external volumes.

Comment: In my system log I also find external volumes

Comment: Me too, that's why I don't think that's the list I remember. I remember it showing just the DMG files that had been opened and mounted. Maybe some sort of Disk Image Mounter log or something.