# How can I know if a user plugged an external storage device into a Mac (such as an external hard drive) and moved/copied any data to and from it?

Tags: macos

How can I know if a user plugged an external storage device (such as an external hard drive) and moved/copied any data to and from it?  Is this recorded in any system logs?.  Any article or resource explaining this?

Comment: I'm unsure about past activity, but you could definitely monitor for this manually, if you can run a program on the computer.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140903/where-can-i-find-the-log-of-all-mounted-volumes mount history, but not file activity.