# Encrypted drive log of mounts/unmounts?

Tags: macos, encryption, apfs, adobe-flash

Do  encrypted  volumes  contain any log telling  when they were mounted and unmounted?
I have several encrypted USB thumb drives and I would like to know whether someone has tried to put them into their computer.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally the practice that logs would be maintained on the system which is doing the mounting etc. On macOS the logs are typically located here: `/var/log/system.log`.

Matteo's answer here shows the various ways that mounting of devices or DMG image files will show up in this log after they're mounted/unmounted.

- [Where can I find the log of all mounted volumes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140903/where-can-i-find-the-log-of-all-mounted-volumes)